# pgfplots: How to selectively remove major grid lines at certain points?

Tags: pgfplots

Following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/306095/2288), I tried to remove the grid lines at `xmin` and `xmax`, but it fails. What is missing here?

Also, how can I input the variables `xmin` and `xmax` in `extra x ticks` without the need to write the numbers manually?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xtick={0,0.5,...,5},
    xmin=0,xmax=5,
    xmajorgrids,
    major x grid style = {line width =2pt,dashed,black},
    extra x ticks={0,5},
    extra x tick labels={},
    extra tick style={
        grid=none,
    },]

        \addplot[mark=none,blue] {x^2};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically this is the same answer as [Symbol 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/364144/95441) ones, but is a bit more "automated", which means, that you now only have *one* place to take care of for setting the `xmin`, `xmax` and `xtick distance` values.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        % =====================================================================
        % state here the `xmin', `xmax' and `xtick distance' values
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\xmin}{0}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\xmax}{5}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\DeltaX}{0.5}
        % =====================================================================
        % calculate the `xtick' positions without drawing the `xmajorgrid' at
        % `xmin' and `xmax'
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\xmintick}{\xmin + \DeltaX}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\nexttick}{\xmin + 2*\DeltaX}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\lasttick}{\xmax - \DeltaX}
    \begin{axis}[
        % set `xmin' and `xmax'
        xmin=\xmin,
        xmax=\xmax,
        % set the `xtick' values using the defined variables
        xtick={\xmintick,\nexttick,...,\lasttick},
        xmajorgrids,
        major x grid style={
            dashed,
            red,
        },
        % add the extra ticks without using the grid lines at `xmin' and `xmax'
        % (for simplicity we can use the defined commands here ...
        extra x ticks={\xmin,\xmax},
%        %  ... but since we have set these values explicitly we can also call
%        %  the values)
%        extra x ticks={
%            \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},
%            \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}
%        },
        % set the style of the extra ticks
        extra tick style={
            % remove the grid
            % by default the `extra tick style' is the same as for the "normal" ticks
            grid=none,
        },
    ]
        \addplot [mark=none,blue] {x^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there: just replace

> ```
> xtick={0,0.5,...,5},
> ```

by

```
xtick={0.5,1,...,4.5},
```

and then remove

> ```
> extra x tick labels={},
> ```

[image]

## Edit

OP asks

> why my solution fails in this way

The idea of this kind of workaround is based on a fact: that [pgfplots](/questions/tagged/pgfplots) uses the `xtick`'s position to draw the grids. Therefore as long as `0` and `5` are in `xtick`, it will draw the line as well as it will draw the line for `0.5`, `1`, `1.5` and so on.

> how can I call the values 'xmin' and 'xmax' anywhere as numeric values?

This is ambiguous. If you mean the values that the user **assigned** as options, (instead of the nature min/max calculated by [pgfplots](/questions/tagged/pgfplots)), then I believe that it can be access by `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}`.

Comment: `xtick distance` also doesn't make any sense when you are using `xtick`.

Comment: It is a pretty solution, but the core of my question still stands; I mean, why does my solution fail in this way, while it doesn't in the other way as in the answer I referred to? Additionally, how can I call the values 'xmin' and 'xmax' anywhere as numeric values?

Comment: @StefanPinnow I forgot to remove `xtick distance` when editing my MWE.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou Please see my edit :)

Comment: I like the \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}. Very handy.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Unfortunately, for `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}`, when I tried to test it `extra x ticks={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}}` it threw an error: _Dimension too large_, what is the reason?

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: @StefanPinnow it fails with me because I didn't write `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}` in the preamble `:/`

Comment: Neither did I but it worked anyway ...